# ASP.Net FAQ library control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-controls

Can someone advise if there is an ASP.NET control that i can use to create an FAQ section on my existing website.

I can build it myself but i was hoping there's an existing library i can just plug in.

Comment: What would such a control look like? FAQ sections of web sites are not standardised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be using [an accordion](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Accordion/Accordion.aspx) or [the jquery version](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

Answer (score 1):

I used jquery ui accordion control in one of the website i worked on. **I would go for server controls only if it's  absolutely necessary**. If your FAQ content gonna be static, you can try jquery ui accordion

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/